# How to use takeImage method in IOS to store photos into photo album

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

The takeImage method is void meaning that it returns nothing, so how do I get the UIImage when I try to take an image on my IOS device. I am using a custom UIImagePickerViewController that doesn't display the standard controls and has custom controls. I have the following method for my UIButton:

```
-(void)shootPicture{
[self.PickerController takePicture];
}
```

Once I captured the UIImage I was going to use the following method `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`, but I couldn't figure out how to get the UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method of UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to get the image that the user picked. Then inside that method, you can grabbed the image like so...

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *pickedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    // Now do something with pickedImage...
}
```

For more information, take a look at the documentation for [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:).